# Using mdframed in an enumeration

Tags: vertical-alignment, enumerate, mdframed

I'm facing a problem with the `enumerate` environment in LaTeX when attempting to create a box using `mdframed` immediately after starting a new item. While the boxing works as expected, it causes a misalignment of the numbers within the `enumerate` environment, see the second item in the screenshot below: The `2.` is not vertically aligned with the other numbers due to the presence of the box created by `mdframed`.

Is there a way to fix this? At least, one should be able to add some kind of negative space manually, right?

---

*Screenshot:*

[image]

---

*MWE:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item\lipsum[1][1-2]
        \begin{mdframed}
            \lipsum[2][1-2]
        \end{mdframed}

        \item\begin{mdframed}
            \lipsum[3][1-2]
        \end{mdframed}

        \item\lipsum[4][1-2]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you just need that simple of box? You could directly use `\fbox` plus `\parbox`.

Comment: @Tom I do just need such a simple box. With `fbox` and `parbox`, the enumeration number is vertically shifted downwards in case the box contains more than one line. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the alignment to top using `[t]` option for `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item\lipsum[1][1-2]
        
\fbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\lipsum[2][1-2]}}

\item\fbox{\parbox[t]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\lipsum[1][1-5]}}

\item\lipsum[4][1-2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]